# matching the value only with a subset of string

Tags: c#

I have this value

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> projectCustomerNameMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {            
            {"Diooiio","Oppo" }
            {"SSoois","RealMe"}
        };
```

which I am reading like this

```
 if( !projectCustomerNameMapping.TryGetValue( (string)data["Project"], out customerName ) )
                    {
                        // if the value wasn't found in the dictionary, use the default
                        customerName = "OnePlus";
                    }
```

My question is above it actually matches the Project and then gives the customerName, but I would like if it contains a value from project it should return the customer name. so if my project has value as "PoC_Diooiio" or "Diooiio" or anything which contains "Diooiio" it should give me customer name "Oppo". How do I fix it?

Comment: Iterate the map's keys and return the value if `key.Contains("Diooiio");`

Comment: can you please show me in a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string search = data["Project"];
var customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping
        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key.IndexOf(search ) != -1 || search.IndexOf(q.Key) != -1)
        .Value ?? "OnePlus";
```

Comment: same issue as i am getting in other answer . it fails. In my dictionary I have "KNF_StOlavs" and the project name I passed is "KNF_StOlavs_validation" and it fails.

Comment: I think I will work now. It checks if the key is contained by the project name, and if the project names is contained by the key

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try using Linq. The below will return a Like resultset for you.

This is just a guide for your code.  It will return the first response it finds, if there is one, and may not always be the one you want.

If it finds nothing, it will return "OPPO"

```cs
         public string findCustomerName(string input)
        {
            var result = projectCustomerNameMapping.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key.Contains(input));
            if (result.Key == null)
                return "OPPO";
            else
                return result.Value;
        }
```

Comment: how should I integrate in my code as you see that if i dont have any matching value then i have default customer as "Oneplus"

Comment: your code doesnt work. I checked with a substring value and it returned false

Comment: Why are you returning the dictionary when I need just the value Oppo

Comment: Updated again.  This should work for you.  Linq if pretty easy to use if you give it a go.  Just need to watch out for null results

Comment: thanks and I did exactly your way but still on checking for susbstring, it fails. In my dictionary I have "KNF_StOlavs" and the project name I passed is "KNF_StOlavs_validation" and it fails. are we missing something

Answer (score 0):

```
string temp = "Diooiio";
if(customerName.contains(temp) == true)
{
   customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping[temp]; 
}
```

You may loop through all the elements of Dictionary for rest.